# magento view.phtml call on cms page with specific product id but getchildhtml method not render

Tags: magento

```
  <?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
    <?php //$_product = $this->getProduct(); 
    $product_id = $_GET['proid'];
    $obj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $_product = $obj->load($product_id); // Enter your Product Id in $product_id
    print_r($_product);
   ?>

                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data'); ?>
                        </div>
                       <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
                   <?php endif;?>

                   <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>


                           <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                               <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                           <?php endif; ?>
                       </div>
                       <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>
                   </div>
                   <?php endif; ?>

                   <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other');?>

    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product.info.review_list'); ?>
</div>`
```

in the above  code getchildhtml() was not render in cms page.please make a solution i know it happen with xml but i dont  get how to do.

Answer (score 0):

Rahul Chittora,can `do this on cms page because this child block is only work on . product view page and it  declared in catalog.xml` and it `always work on catalog_product_view layout`.

Lot of work need  do `if want do this type  works using call of child  from catalog_product page layout  to cms page layout.`

I suggest do `some custom code or used quick view extension,which may do this`